# Changing page title as it appears in MediaWiki category

Tags: mediawiki, categories, wiki, mediawiki-templates

I've been trying to use DEFAULTSORT to sort pages based on a template parameter instead of the page title. This is how it appears at the top of the template:

```
{{DEFAULTSORT:{{{Username}}}}}
```

This is how it appears after the argument is transcluded:

```
{{DEFAULTSORT:d3xus}}
```

It would be nice for it to appear in categories as d3xus and not D3xus. There's no change in how the page is sorted because they both begin with the same symbol. Using an extension or magic word, is it possible to change how a page appears when viewed in a category? DEFAULTSORT only changes how the page is sorted with respect to other pages in the same category, but it does not change the page title in the category.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing. If you want to change the page title regardless where it is displayed, you can use [`$wgCapitalLinks`](http://Manual:$wgCapitalLinks) or [`{{DISPLAYTITLE}}`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words).

---

Actually it seems there is such a thing: [Extension:Semantic Title](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Title). It is very hacky though (and you need to install Semantic MediaWiki).

Comment: DISPLAYTITLE only works on the page the magic word is present on. It doesn't change how a page appears on a category page.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually impossible without a bigger change in the code. There is a task for it in Wikimedia's bug/feature tracking software Phabricator: [T19212](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T19212), but it's actually stalled :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- *Method 1:* Add to your MediaWiki site: `{{DISPLAYTITLE:d3xus}}` and `[[Category:d3xus]]`.
- *Method 2:* https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Title

Comment: Method 1: That wouldn't change the displayed title in the list of pages on the category page :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution using the old way, which could even be a real fix and optional behavior in MediaWiki with just a few lines of changes if they wanted.

These edits will use the category sort key option to change the category list page displayed title.

```
[[Category:Category name|MySortKey]]
```

Then the category page looks like

```
A
 * AnotherSortKey

M
 * MySortKey
```

Then the category listing will behave as it did a long time ago, and how it did sort of if the semantic extensions were installed, where the listings page name follows the user supplied sort key.

---

### The edits

In 1.39, and other versions, if you own the mediawiki install, you can easily edit the includes/CategoryViewer.php to pass the original custom sort key from the [[Category:Category name|MySortKey]] link, which was stored verbatim in the database, to the category link build builder.

**Important!!**
I do not recommend editing the MediaWiki code in general, unless you are sitting on the same version for years anyway and can handle some QA testing, or willing to babysit and reimplement the fix after every upgrade.

The fix is a few lines in the same 'includes/CategoryViewer.php' file. This example is for 1.39. Your version's code may differ, but the important parts should be there in probably any version.

```
includes/CategoryViewer.php in 1.39
```

###### Find 'AddPage()':

1. Copy and comment-out original version.
2. Add a '$sortkeyprefix' parameter for passing the original user 'sortKey' as the last parameter.
3. Then pass the '$sortkeyprefix' as the last argument of 'generateLink'.

```php
public function addPage(
    PageReference $page, string $sortkey, int $pageLength, bool $isRedirect = false, ?string $sortkeyprefix = null
): void {
    $this->articles[] = $this->generateLink( 'page', $page, $isRedirect, $sortkeyprefix );

    $this->articles_start_char[] =
        $this->languageConverter->convert( $this->collation->getFirstLetter( $sortkey ) );
}
/*
public function addPage(
    PageReference $page, string $sortkey, int $pageLength, bool $isRedirect = false
): void {
    $this->articles[] = $this->generateLink( 'page', $page, $isRedirect );

    $this->articles_start_char[] =
        $this->languageConverter->convert( $this->collation->getFirstLetter( $sortkey ) );
}
*/
```

###### Find 'doCategoryQuery()':

1. Find the loop section in this function that calls addPage()
2. Copy and comment-out original version sections.
3. Make a new local variable '$sortKeyPrefix = $row->cl_sortkey_prefix;' which will hold the original user requested sortkey/pagename, from the already fetched database row.
4. Optionally pass this to the $title->getCategorySortkey( $sortKeyPrefix ) instead of letting it get it from $row again.
5. Add the new '$sortKeyPrefix' as the new last parameter of the 'addPage()' call at the bottom

```php
$count = 0;
foreach ( $res as $row ) {
    $title = Title::newFromRow( $row );
    $linkCache->addGoodLinkObjFromRow( $title, $row );

    $sortKeyPrefix = $row->cl_sortkey_prefix;

    if ( $row->cl_collation === '' ) {
        // Hack to make sure that while updating from 1.16 schema
        // and db is inconsistent, that the sky doesn't fall.
        // See r83544. Could perhaps be removed in a couple decades...
        $humanSortkey = $row->cl_sortkey;
    } else {
        $humanSortkey = $title->getCategorySortkey( $sortKeyPrefix );
    }
    /*
    $title = Title::newFromRow( $row );
    $linkCache->addGoodLinkObjFromRow( $title, $row );

    if ( $row->cl_collation === '' ) {
        // Hack to make sure that while updating from 1.16 schema
        // and db is inconsistent, that the sky doesn't fall.
        // See r83544. Could perhaps be removed in a couple decades...
        $humanSortkey = $row->cl_sortkey;
    } else {
        $humanSortkey = $title->getCategorySortkey( $row->cl_sortkey_prefix );
    }
    */

    if ( ++$count > $this->limit ) {
        # We've reached the one extra which shows that there
        # are additional pages to be had. Stop here...
        $this->nextPage[$type] = $humanSortkey;
        break;
    }
    if ( $count == $this->limit ) {
        $this->prevPage[$type] = $humanSortkey;
    }

    if ( $title->getNamespace() === NS_CATEGORY ) {
        $cat = Category::newFromRow( $row, $title );
        $this->addSubcategoryObject( $cat, $humanSortkey, $row->page_len );
    } elseif ( $title->getNamespace() === NS_FILE ) {
        $this->addImage( $title, $humanSortkey, $row->page_len, $row->page_is_redirect );
    } else {
        $this->addPage( $title, $humanSortkey, $row->page_len, $row->page_is_redirect, $sortKeyPrefix );
        //$this->addPage( $title, $humanSortkey, $row->page_len, $row->page_is_redirect );
    }
}
```

Did this today on a site with maybe 8K pages, and it works fine, and wanted to share.

---

Added comment with reference to this post to https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T24586 for the directly SortKey fix request.

The other https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T19212 for DISPLAYTITLE mentioned here will add a comment also.